# apt-cache depends <software> listing seems not recursive/complete or effective for offline installation

Tags: apt, dependencies, offline

How do I make sure the dependency listing is recursive and also download using apt (sudo apt-get download < package >) happens recursively?

I am trying to download each and every .deb file in a local folder and sudo apt-get -download is not effective in downloading given package along with the dependencies.It only downloads a particular package.

So, I am doing

```
sudo apt-cache depends doxygen
```

The output is:

```
  doxygen                                                                      
  Depends: libc6                                                               
  Depends: libclang1-3.6                                                           
  Depends: libgcc1                                                               
  Depends: libstdc++6                                                               
  Conflicts: graphviz                                                              
  Suggests: doxygen-latex                                                        
  Suggests: doxygen-doc                                                             
  Suggests: doxygen-gui                                      
  Suggests: graphviz                
    graphviz:i386
```

So, while doing

```
sudo apt-get download  < each dependency mentioned above >

sudo dpkg -i <each dependency mentioned above>
```

I get error saying `libllvm` is not installed, for one of the dependency.

How do I make sure the dependency listing is recursive and also download using apt happens recursively?

Comment: The recursive list is likely to be **very** large. How deep do you want to go?

Comment: It is not limited. Complete depth, because I want to go through each dependency before going to my offline machine so that I do not get stuck up at my offline machine while doing installation.                                    It would be great if I can understand the hierarchy too of dependencies, but as of now on google search, I could n't find any such solution..

Comment: Really what you want is not completely recursive list of all dependencies - it's the dependencies *that are not already installed on the target (offline) machine* - for that, you can use `apt install --print-uris <package>` on the offline machine.

Answer (score 1):

apt-depends (or apt depends in 16.04 and later) have a --recurse flag, but it's not as useful as you may expect:

```
$ apt depends --recurse hello | grep Depends | wc -l

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

102003
```

Your entire system is made of many thousands of interdependent packages. The applications you install on top of your system may depend only on a few packages...but indirectly on most of them.

**Happily, there are better and simpler answers**.

One simple way to determine uninstalled dependencies is to use apt's --simulate flag:

```
$ apt install --simulate doxygen
```

Another simple way to determine uninstalled dependencies is to use the install-script feature in Synaptic.